# Why doesn't If Not IsEmpty filter out empty strings?

Tags: vba, if-statement, string

What is wrong with my `If` condition?

```
If Not IsEmpty(Wrkgps_L3) And Not IsEmpty(Wrkgps_L4) Then
    Wrkgps_L3L4 = Wrkgps_L3 & "," & Wrkgps_L4
End If
```

The `Not` condition doesn't seem to work. The code within the `If` statement gets executed even when both `Wrkgps_L3` and `Wrkgps_L4` are empty strings.

### Update:

`Wrkgps_L3` and `Wrkgps_L4` are variables that contain results returned from a function. I noticed that `IsEmpty(Wrkgps_L3) = False` even though `Wrkgps_L3 = ""`. I had to rewrite my code to

```
If (Wrkgps_L3 <> "") And (Wrkgps_L4 <> "") Then
```

In any case, I am still intrigued to know why `IsEmpty` doesn't work on variables with `""`?

Comment: Is it possible you're confusing `Null` and `Empty`? e.g. `Not IsEmpty(null)` returns true

Comment: I think you need to apply brackets around the conditions like this     If ((Not IsEmpty(Wrkgps_L3)) And (Not IsEmpty(Wrkgps_L4)))

Comment: I'd say you need more parenthesis :))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Visual Basic, `Empty` and `""` (an empty string) are two different things. `Empty` is the uninitialized state of a `Variant` variable, and `IsEmpty` tests whether a `Variant` variable has the `Empty` value:

```
Dim x As Variant
If IsEmpty(x) Then
    Debug.Print "x is empty"
End If
```

As you've observed, you must compare against `""` when checking whether a `String` variable contains an empty string.

Comment: The only thing to add is that `If x = Empty` returns `True` in case `x` contains an empty string. But don't do this, it's an implicit conversion sugar which is better to avoid unless you know for sure what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are strings, you could also:

```
If Len(Wrkgps_L3) + Len(Wrkgps_L4) = 0 Then
   ' They're both empty string variables
Else
   ' One or the other contains at least one character
End If
```